# Spring Native custom name for generated executables

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spring-native

I want to change the name of the generated executables in Spring Native with Maven.
Default is the `<artifactId>` from the `pom.xml`.

If we want to specify the name of the resulting .jar file, we have an option to configure this with `<finalName>` inside the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` plugin configuration.

Is there a similar configuration property to allow the same behavior for the `native-image-plugin`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution using `<imageName>` inside the `native-image-plugin` configuration like:

`pom.xml` (only part of file shown)

```xml
                    ...
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                        <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <imageName>app</imageName>
                        </configuration>
                    ...
```